# General Errors: 'Article Updated From Different Page' while creating instant article in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I am creating Facebook instant article under Development Articles with its sample code. I have configured the canonical url properly and my code is as below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://fb.clinate.com">
<meta property="op:markup_version" content="v1.0">
</head>
<body>
<article>
  <header>
    <!-- The title and subtitle shown in your Instant Article -->
    <h1>Article Title</h1>
    <h2>Article Subtitle</h2>

    <!-- The date and time when your article was originally published -->
    <time class="op-published" datetime="2014-11-11T04:44:16Z">November 11th, 4:44 PM</time>

    <!-- The date and time when your article was last updated -->
    <time class="op-modified" dateTime="2014-12-11T04:44:16Z">December 11th, 4:44 PM</time>

    <!-- The authors of your article -->
    <address>
      <a>Author Name</a>
      Author description.
    </address>
    <address>
      <a>TR Vishwanath</a>
      Vish is a scholar and a gentleman.
    </address>

    <!-- A kicker for your article --> 
    <h3 class="op-kicker">
      This is a kicker
    </h3>

  </header>

  <!-- Article body goes here -->

  <!-- Body text for your article -->
  <p> Article content </p> 


  <footer>
    <!-- Credits for your article -->
    <aside>Acknowledgements</aside>

    <!-- Copyright details for your article -->
    <small>Legal notes</small>
  </footer>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add it in Production Article and also deleted and tried on new page, but it still giving same error. The detail error message is as below

> General Errors: Article Updated From Different Page: The article cannot be updated from this page. Please use the page that originally created the article to update it.

What does it mean `Updated From Different Page`. I have created only one page in my account.

Answer (score 0):

its a bug for  instant artical.its not your post problem.At a time if you give 3 or 4 post.then show 1 post is not live.so take your time when you post something

Answer (score 0):

wait a while brother. if you have linked it to other page, keep that unpublished.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.